# Form1.Show() not working with asyn await

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a login form where i am checking if the password is correct to login if not to show a message.

the message showing perfect, but when i try to enter correct login details the form.show() not working. the following is my code.

```
    private void LoginpictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Login();


    }


    private async Task Login()
    {

        if (await AuthorizeUser.isUserAuthorized(UserNamealphaBlendTextBox.Text, PasswordalphaBlendTextBox.Text))
        {

            //this.Close();

            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.MdiParent = main;
            frm.Show();



        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password or User name incorrect.");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Probably `main` is not the form that you can see and probably it's an instance that you created just in memory without showing. (Just a guess). Anyway, at the moment question is off-topic. Read [mcve]

Comment: Add a breakpoint at if condition and check whetger condition is executing or not

Comment: condition is executing. yes

Comment: Try `frm.MdiParent = this`

Comment: there is no issue with mdi, the issue is async await by passing this and not showing at all.

Comment: @Manzoor_Developer http://i.imgur.com/jjLDhiC.gifv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt changing this line:

```
frm.MdiParent = main;
```

to this line:

```
frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
```

**OR** in case `main` is an mdi container, then make sure to:

```
main.IsMdiContainer = true;
```

before you actually set `frm.MdiParent` to it.